# How to move the filter panel in admin product page OC 3.0.2.0?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I would like to move the filter panel in admin product page to the top of the page. In OC 2x it is in the top of the page and this is more convenient and you will have a lot more space when you later add more column to the form.
Is this an easy task to move the panel and how can I do it ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have the knowledge about HTML structure of opencart. You are able to set the same layout which is in opencart 2.x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this file:

```
admin\view\template\catalog\product_list.twig
```

Find:

```
<div id="filter-product" class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9 col-sm-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
```

Change it to:

```
<div id="filter-product">
```

Find:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-12">
```

Change it to:

```
<div>
```

Then go to your admin dashboard / Gear icon / Refresh

Comment: Thanks a million for the help !
With this modification filters goes above the products, each filter on new row.
Any chance to modify it to looks like OpenCart 2.x ?

Modified page: [link](https://prnt.sc/lmdmh8)
Opencart 2.x: [link](https://prnt.sc/lmdmb6)

Comment: You are welcome, in the same file replace all `<div class="form-group` with `<div class="form-group col-sm-4`